# Call a function returned by a lua script from C

Tags: lua, lua-api

Given a lua file like

```
-- foo.lua
return function (i)
  return i
end
```

How can I load this file with the C API and call the returned function?
I just need function calls beginning with `luaL_loadfile`/`luaL_dostring`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [loaded](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_load) chunk is just a regular function. Loading the module from C can be thought of like this:

```lua
return (function()  -- this is the chunk compiled by load

    -- foo.lua
    return function (i)
      return i
    end

end)()  -- executed with call/pcall
```

All you have to do is load the chunk and call it, its return value is your function:

```c
// load the chunk
if (luaL_loadstring(L, script)) {
    return luaL_error(L, "Error loading script: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
}

// call the chunk (function will be on top of the stack)
if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0)) {
    return luaL_error(L, "Error running chunk: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
}

// call the function
lua_pushinteger(L, 42); // function arg (i)
if (lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0)) {
    return luaL_error(L, "Error calling function: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks, that's a really helpful semantic of 'chunk'. Actually, one of the versions I've tried so far was similar, only that I my first call was `lua_pcall(L, 0, 0)`,  which discarded the result. That left me wondering why there was no return value.